# Source follower input/output swing

Tags: analog, source-follower

I found in [this](https://books.google.it/books?id=uU5EAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA270&dq=Flipped%20voltage%20follower&hl=it&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi9udTX3u77AhUQHewKHRTiDoUQ6AF6BAgFEAM#v=onepage&q=Flipped%20voltage%20follower&f=false) book at the page 271 a definition of the source follower input/output swing ( that i didn`t know as:

$$ V_{in-pp} = V_{dd} - ( Vt + 2.V_{ds-sat} )$$

I tried to understand how to calculate this paramater (I've tried to consider the condition for having the MOSFET in saturation V<sub>ds</sub> > V<sub>d-sat</sub> and active V<sub>gs</sub> > V<sub>t</sub>), but I didn`t arrive to the same result.
Considering:
V<sub>ds</sub> > V<sub>d-sat</sub>

and

V<sub>in</sub>= V<sub>out</sub> + V<sub>GS</sub>

I obtained

V<sub>out</sub> < V<sub>dd</sub> - V<sub>d-sat</sub>

or equivalently

V<sub>in</sub> < V<sub>dd</sub> +V<sub>gs</sub>  - V<sub>d-sat</sub>

Can somebody help me?

Book Name: Analog/RF and Mixed-Signal Circuit Systematic Design (pag271)
Schematic:
[image]

Comment: Please show us all of your work.

Comment: I change a little bit the question adding what i was trying to do..

Comment: Seems incorrect to me...Should be Vdd-2Vdsat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can arrive at their answer by adding the following assumptions, which are reasonable enough though not universally true:

1. \$V_{in}\$ can never go above \$V_{DD}\$ or below ground.
2. The current source \$I_b\$ needs headroom of at least \$V_{dsat}\$.
3. We can approximate \$V_{gs} = V_{dsat} + V_{t} \$

Then the maximum value of the input is just \$V_{DD}\$.

The minimum value of the *output* is \$V_{dsat}\$, so:

$$V_{in,min} = V_{GS} + V_{out,min} = (V_t + V_{dsat}) + V_{dsat}$$

Thus:

$$V_{in,pp} = V_{DD} - (V_t + 2 V_{dsat})$$